# How to count the length of a post title?

Tags: php, title

Let's say that I have an entry titled **Crime & Punishment**

I tried to count the number of characters of my entry titles using the following line:

```
echo strlen( get_the_title() );
```

I expected the code would give me 18 characters for **Crime & Punishment**, but the result turned out to be 23 characters.

The code above didn't give me my desired result since it reads the symbols within the title as a *HTML code*. Is there any workaround for such case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two problems:

1. The `&` is encoded as `&amp;`, so you have to use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) first.
2. Multi-byte characters need more than one byte, and `strlen()` will fail with them. [Don’t use strlen()](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/).

So use something like this:

```
$title  = html_entity_decode( get_the_title(), ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8' );
$length = mb_strlen( $title, 'utf-8' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php echo strip_tags(strlen(get_the_title())); ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately... that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm not sure why, but your code still giving me the same result as what I'm using initially...